# Remove String Captured in Regex Group

Tags: sed

I have a file that contains the following content with tags/tag/volume_tags. I want to use `sed` command to remove `stackId = AnyValue` inside tags/tag only (not volume_tags).

Input:

```
tags = {
    Name    = var.stack_id
    StackId = bar
}

tags = 

{
    Name    = var.stack_id
    StackId = bar
}

tag = {
    StackId = foo
}

volume_tags = {
  StackId = bar
}
```

Output:

```
tags = {
    Name    = var.stack_id
}

tags = 

{
    Name    = var.stack_id
}

tag = {
}

volume_tags = {
  StackId = bar
}
```

I try creating Regex that captures the tags/tag block and group `StackId = AnyValue` with `(\s*StackId.\s*=.*)` and aim to use `sed` command to replace that group with an empty string. How to do so using `sed`? or any other suggestion to achieve this?

```sh
^tag.*\s*=?\s*{(\s*.*\s*)?(\s*StackId.\s*=.*)\s*}
```

Comment: The `sed` command to delete a line is just `d` and it can be preceded by a `sed` address or address range. So, with GNU `sed` (you apparently use this one) `/^\s*StackId\s*=/d` deletes any line containing `StackId =` with zero or more leading spaces, zero or more spaces before the `=` sign and followed by anything. Just put this in a block `{...}` such that you can further limit its scope with an address range in the form `/regex1/,/regex2/`. Here `regex1` is `^\s*tags\?\s*=\s*{\s*$` and `regex2`is `^\s*}\s*$`.

Comment: Remember that the `?` GNU `sed` extension for 0 or 1 must be escaped (`\?`) in Basic Regular Expressions. Use the `-E` option of GNU `sed` to enable Extended Regular Expressions and avoid this. But then you will have to escape `{` and `}`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I've got the idea but I'm still stuck getting this to work. I'm a basic user of sed. Address range seems to be so advance to me. Would you be able to come up with a sample for this use case?

Comment: Address range is not advanced. In your case it's just a regular expression that's supposed to match the first line of the range, a comma, and a regular expression that's supposed to match the last line of the range.  Then, there is the command to apply to the range. The syntax is `/regex1/,/regex2/ {command}` (omit the `{}` if the command is simple). In your case: `/^\s*tags\?\s*=\s*{\s*$/,/^\s*}\s*$/{/^\s*StackId\s*=/d}`. What don't you understand? Regular expressions? `sed` itself? Did you look at the documentation (`man sed` or `info sed` or maybe `info gsed` if you use GNU `sed`)?

Comment: By the way, in your example the second `tags =` has its opening curly brace (`{`) on a separate line. Is it intentional? If yes, what other similar irregularities do you have?

Comment: Yes, it is intentional. What I'm trying to say is that every whitespace can have a new line. My actual input use case can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/QL3rNS/1/

Comment: OK. If any space in your example can contain newlines things will be more difficult. Sorry, I did not get this from the beginning. Can you have nested groups? Can there be a `tags = {...}` inside another `something = {...}`? And are there things that never change like, for instance, the group names (`tags`) always start at the beginning of a line?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It is actually a [Terraform tag] (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging) if you're familiar with Terraform. It is usually placed inside resource = {...}

Comment: Well, if anything is possible, you'd better try to find a parser for the Terraform language and use it. `sed`, `awk` and all other general purpose text processing tools are fine for simple to moderately complex input formats but as soon as you have a real and sophisticated language (for instance when constructs can be nested), trying to parse them with these tools becomes a real nightmare. You'll always encounter a new exception that breaks your code.

Comment: I think we don't have to worry about nested group right? As long as we can capture the `\s*tags\?` then remove `\s*StackId\s*=.*` line inside that. I feel @Potong's approach would be the ideal solution that works.

Comment: Potong's approach will not handle nested groups correctly. For instance, it will close a `tags` group on the first encountered `}`, which could be the closing curly brace of an inner group... And then it will not remove a `StackId` following this closing curly brace but still inside the `tags` group. Conversely, it will completely miss a `tags` group inside another group. I really encourage you to not waste your time and, if it exists, use a real parser for this language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^tags\?\>/{:a;n;/\<StackId\>/d;/^}$/!ba}' file
```

If a line begins with `tag` or `tags` fetch the following lines until one beginning/ending `}`.

If the collection of lines above contains the word `StackId` delete that line only.

N.B. Assumes only one such id per stanza.

---

```
cat <<\! | sed -f - file
/^tags\?\>/{
:a
n
/\<StackId\>/d
/^}$/!ba
}
!
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a fine approach, but I'm struggling to test this in OSX. Would you be able to provide OSX(bash) one? Also, I'm quite new to sed. Can you explain `:a` `n` `>` `<` `!ba` or point me to the document?

Comment: This would be the ideal solution. Could you please help to address this error in OSX(Bash). `"/^tags\?\>/{:a;n;/\<Sta ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Comment: @DaneSavot the metacharacters `\<`, `\>` and `\?` are special in a regexp. The first two are zero width and mark the beginning and end of a word (much the same way `^` and `$` work for start and end of a line, a word being a-zA-Z0-9_)  the last represents a optional character in this case singular or plural. OSX is a mystery to me as I believe it is built with an old version of BSD (I stand to be corrected) but perhaps putting the one line in a file and replace each `;` by a newline and also a newline before the last `}` and then invoking the file using the `-f` option would work. See edit.

Comment: this is very helpful. Now, I'm trying to understand each line. Can you explain `:a` `n` `!ba`?

Comment: @DaneSavot the `:a` is a loop place holder, the `n` print the current line in the pattern space and the fetches the next and the `/../!ba` jumps to the `a` place holder if the regexp is not matched. HTH

Answer (score 2):

sed is line-oriented. It can perform actions on ranges of lines:

```sh
sed -e '
    /^[[:space:]]*tags\{0,1\}[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*$/, /^[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*$/ {
        /^[[:space:]]*StackId[[:space:]]*=/ d
    }
'
```

- `\{0,1\}` is equivalent to more usual `?` in other regex versions
- sed can't portably do case-insensitive matching but there are workarounds

Comment: I don't understand this expression. What is <input and / d } '    ?

Comment: `<input` was probably a copy-paste error from the environment @jhnc used for testing. I removed it. `d` is the `sed` delete command. What this `sed`program does is: delete (`d`) all lines containing `StackId =` between a line equal to `tag = {` or `tags = {` and a line equal to just `}`. The `[[:space:]]*` are simply the `sed` way to say zero or more (`*`) space, tab... The exact list of characters matching `[[:space:]]` depends on your locale. And `\{0,1\}` is the portable way to say 0 or 1 of the preceding character (the final `s` of `tags` here).

Comment: Note that, if you use GNU `sed` (just guessing), you can replace all `[[:space:]]` by `\s` and `\{0,1\}` by `\?`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet `<input` it was deliberate. It tells sed to take input from a file called `input`. perhaps I should have also added `>output` for the output

Comment: @jhnc Ooops, sorry for that, I really thought it was a piece of HTML. I feel so stupid. Please restore it if you wish.

Comment: I try converting `[[:space:]]*` to `\s*` because newline[s] can be expected in each white space. ex. `tags = 
[newlines]
{
    Name    = var.stack_id
    StackId = bar
}` and `[[:space:]]` probably matches space, tab only. `sed -e '
    /^\s*tags\{0,1\}\s*=\s*{\s*$/, /^\s*}\s*$/ {
        /^\s*StackId\s*=/ d
    }
'` yet doesn't match and remove StackId line either.

Comment: I see. Look at potong's answer. It should be what you want. And no, `[[:space:]]` probably matches newlines in your locale. It's just that you did not understand yet that `sed` is **line-oriented**. All regular expressions you see in this answer are to be matched inside one line only, not several consecutive lines. Again see potong's answer for a more sophisticated solution that can operate on a group of consecutive lines.